# `require': cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I have created a module which then I would inherit in my class to use its methods. But when I run the code. I get error.

**mixins2.rb**

```
module ImageUtils 
    def self.status
        puts "Image storing Module"
    end

    def self.preview(image)
    end 

    def self.transfer(image, destination)
    end
end
```

**run.rb**

```
require 'mixins2'

ImageUtils.status
```

When I run the file `$ ruby run.rb`. I get following errors:

```
/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- mixins2 (LoadError)
    from /Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from run.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This change was made over 5 years ago, one would think that tutorials would have been updated by now :-/

Comment: @JörgWMittag the tutorials i am following are at codeschool. I didn't realised they were that old. The company itself is new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use require_relative:

```
require_relative 'mixins2'

ImageUtils.status
```